# NumPy/PyTorch extract subsets of images

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch

In Numpy, given a stack of large images `A` of `size(N,hl,wl)`, and coordinates x of size(N) and y of size(N) I want to get smaller images of size (N,16,16)

In a for loop it would look like this:

```
B=numpy.zeros((N,16,16))
for i in range(0,N):
  B[i,:,:]=A[i,y[i]:y[i]+16,x[i]:x[i]+16]
```

But can I do this just with indexing? 
Bonus question: Will this indexing also work in `pytorch`? If not how can I implement this there?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Yes, they are both good, but yours assumes different slices for every sample which was that I was looking for.. HArder to move to torch though without looping over samples. tensorflow has an extract_glimpses function that works for now, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple really with [`view_as_windows` from `scikit-image`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows), to get those sliding windowed views as a 6D array with the fourth axis being singleton. Then, use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to select the ones we want based off the `y` and `x` indices for indexing into the second and third axes of the windowed array to get our `B`.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

BSZ = 16, 16 # Blocksize
A6D = view_as_windows(A,(1,BSZ[0],BSZ[1]))
B_out = A6D[np.arange(N),y,x,0]
```

**Explanation**

To explain to other readers on what's really going on with the problem, here's a sample run on a smaller dataset and with a blocksize of `(2,2)` -

1) Input array (3D) :

```
In [78]: A
Out[78]: 
array([[[ 5,  5,  3,  5,  3,  8],
        [ 5,  *2,  6,  2,  2,  4],
        [ 4,  3,  4,  9,  3,  8],
        [ 6,  3,  3, 10,  4,  5],
        [10,  2,  5,  7,  6,  7],
        [ 5,  4,  2,  5,  2, 10]],

       [[ 4,  9,  8,  4,  9,  8],
        [ 7, 10,  8,  2, 10,  9],
        [10,  *9,  3,  2,  4,  7],
        [ 5, 10,  8,  3,  5,  4],
        [ 6,  8,  2,  4, 10,  4],
        [ 2,  8,  6,  2,  7,  5]],

       [[ *4,  8,  7,  2,  9,  9],
        [ 2, 10,  2,  3,  8,  8],
        [10,  7,  5,  8,  2, 10],
        [ 7,  4, 10,  9,  6,  9],
        [ 3,  4,  9,  9, 10,  3],
        [ 6,  4, 10,  2,  6,  3]]])
```

2) y and x indices to index into the second and third axes :

```
In [79]: y
Out[79]: array([1, 2, 0])

In [80]: x
Out[80]: array([1, 1, 0])
```

3) Finally the desired output, which is a block each from each of the 2D slice along the first axis and whose starting point (top left corner point) is `(y,x)` on that 2D slice. Refer to the asterisks in A for those  -

```
In [81]: B
Out[81]: 
array([[[ 2,  6],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 9,  3],
        [10,  8]],

       [[ 4,  8],
        [ 2, 10]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

In numpy slicing is very simple and the same logic works with a pytorch example. For example

```
imgs = np.random.normal(size=(16,24,24))
imgs[:,0:12,0:12].shape
imgs_tensor = torch.from_numpy(imgs)
imgs_tensor[:,0:12,0:12].size()
```

where the first `:` in the slicing indicates to select all the images in the batch. The 2nd and 3rd `:` indicates the slicing for height and width.

Comment: thanks. But was looking for what happens when you want to slce out differeent regions for every image

Comment: Are you looking at torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of extract_glimpse similar with `tf.image.extract_glimpse` in PyTorch.  It should be satisfied your need:
https://github.com/jimmysue/xvision/blob/main/xvision/ops/extract_glimpse.py#L14